# MongoDB SECONDARY replica keeps failing on STARTUP2

Tags: replication, mongodb

I'm converting standalone existing MongoDB instance to a replica set for backing up without affecting primary instance. To test minimal replica deployment I've set up two MongoDB instances on the same machine:

- `127.0.0.1:27017` — existing DB with 110GB data;
- `127.0.0.1:27018` — new instance with clean DB.

Both instances have:

- different data dirs (`/var/lib/mongo_r0` and `/var/lib/mongo_r1`) with correct read/write permissions under `mongod`;
- separate systemd units (`mongod_r0` and `mongod_r1`);
- the same replicaSet settings in configs:

  ```
  replication:
    replSetName: rs0
  ```

### What I'm doing

1. Run both instances with `systemctl start mongod_r{0,1}`. r0 and r1 start correctly.
2. Login to first shell. 27017 is shown as `SECONDARY` for now.
3. Run `rs.initiate()` on 27017.
4. Add second node to replica set with `rs.add( { host: "127.0.0.1:27018" } )`.
5. Re-login to first shell. Now it's introduces itself as PRIMARY, and `rs.status()` shows:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    ...
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "127.0.0.1:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            ...
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "127.0.0.1:27018",
            "health" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "STARTUP2",
            ...
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    ...
}
```

`htop` and `iostat` show massive increase of CPU and disk usage, which show initial replication stated.

After several minutes `127.0.0.1:27018` suddenly fails without any error. `rs.status()` on first instance shows:

```
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        ...
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27018",
        "health" : 0,
        "state" : 8,
        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
        "uptime" : 0,
        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Connection refused",
        "configVersion" : -1
        ...
    }
],
```

It I try to get size of DB dirs, it shows:

```
108G    /var/lib/mongo_r0/
3.5G    /var/lib/mongo_r1/
```

which means at least **some parts of data** were replicated.

What I'm doing wrong? I've tried two-machines replica and three-ones config with ARBITER instance, but initial replication always fails in several minutes in STARTUP2.

Comment: did you check the replication and security options in mongod.conf of primary node.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan The only setting is `replSetName: rs0` in `replication` section, as i've pointed in question. No other settings exists both in primary and secondary nodes config.

Comment: What is the RAM size of the machine? How many indexes do you have and size?

Comment: 64GB RAM. Two databases with 4 collections per db. Each collection has one unique default index (_id) and one non-unique.

Comment: UPD. Sorry, this server has 32GB RAM. At first look, your guess about OOM is right. I'll check RAM limits and write soon.